# Есть ли в предложении бессоюзная связь?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

> (1) Они сидели поджав ноги. (2) Мальчики спиной ко мне – я видел их тоненькие шеи, а девочка – лицом.

В тесте ОГЭ предложение (2) характеризуется как сложное с бессоюзной и сочинительной связью. Так ли это? Не является ли "я видел их тоненькие шеи" вставной конструкцией?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(1) Мальчики спиной ко мне – (2) я видел их тоненькие шеи, а (3) девочка – лицом.**

1) Да, все верно, между предложениями 1 и 2 бессоюзная связь, обозначенная тире, между 1 и 3 сочинительная связь, союз А.

2) Вариант **с сочинением и подчинением**: Мальчики стояли ко мне спиной, так что я видел их тоненькие шеи, а девочка стояла лицом.

Это же предложение можно (и даже лучше) оформить **со вставкой**: Мальчики спиной ко мне – **я видел их тоненькие шеи**, – а девочка лицом.

Сравнить: Она повесила трубку – **аппарат был рядом**, – но ещё долго молчала.

Answer (score 1):

«Я видел их тоненькие шеи» здесь — часть сложного предложения, пояснительная конструкция, которая является логическим продолжением, дополнением той части, которая стоит перед тире. С ее помощью автор объясняет, почему он решил, что мальчики сидели к нему спиной.

Согласно правилам, если перед пояснительной конструкцией нет слов *а именно, то есть* и т. п., то ее открывает тире: «Хозяев не было дома — дверь была закрыта». Подробнее: http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/prostoe-oslozhnennoe-predlozhenie-10915/obosoblennye-i-neobosoblennye-chleny-predlozheniia-10940/re-0f51a482-f8f9-4d28-93a5-d006a75852b9.

Вставные конструкции, как правило, вносят какие-то уточнения, пояснения, поправки и выделяются из текста, словно инородные элементы: «Я пошел спать (было 22:00)». Основная мысль здесь в том, что человек пошел спать, дополнение о времени — второстепенно. В вашем же предложении автор обращает внимание на то, что он видел лишь шеи сидящих спиной мальчиков, тогда как девочка сидела к нему лицом. Такое противопоставление делает невозможной интерпретацию обсуждаемой части как вставной конструкции.

Таким образом, предложение действительно сложное с бессоюзной (часть после тире) и сочинительной связью (после союза *а*).